# Python using XML reading multiple inner tags

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to read the following XML code using python.

```
<Product productCode="2" productCategory="ABC" productClass="SOMETHING" salable="true" statusCode="ACTIVE" outage="false">
    <PriceList>
        <Currency type ="NATIVE" symbol="US$">
            <Pricing priceCode="EATIN" catalogPrice="2.00" netPrice="2.00" tax="0.09" grossPrice="2.09"/>
        </Currency>
    </PriceList>
</Product>
```

I need to get the catalog price.

Here is my code. I am not sure how to get catalog price. I guess i do not know how to get this data.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse("US_2171_ProductPricing_20170206233707.xml")
# doc.getElementsByTagName returns NodeList
# name = doc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]
# print(name.firstChild.data)
products = doc.getElementsByTagName("Product")
for product in products:
    productCodeID = product.getAttribute("productCode")
    statusCode = product.getAttribute("statusCode")  
    catalogPrice = pricing.getElementsByTagName("catalogPrice")
    print("productCode:%s , statusCode:%s, catalogPrice:%s" % (productCodeID, statusCode, catalogPrice))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do use the beautifulsoup library. This should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_text = open('US_2171_ProductPricing_20170206233707.xml').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_text, 'html.parser')
products = soup.findAll('product')
data = [(p['productcode'],
         p['statuscode'],
         p.findAll('pricing')[0]['catalogprice'])
        for p in products]

for items in data:
    print(', '.join(items))
```

Comment: Thanks this works.  How do i print the data single set with no braces and line break per set
[('1', 'ACTIVE', '1.09'), ('2', 'ACTIVE', '1.19'), ('3', 'ACTIVE', '1.19'), ('4', 'ACTIVE', '1.79')]
like:
1,ACTIVE,1.09 (line break)
2,ACTIVE,1.19
etc

Comment: I updated my answer to help you print the data. Please choose this as the accepted answer if you are satisfied

Comment: @mikepat I would appreciate it if you choose this as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already got everything figured out. Just get all the pricing inside every product and loop through them.

```
for product in products:
    pricings = product.getElementsByTagName("Pricing")
    for pricing in pricings:
        print pricing.getAttribute("catalogPrice")
```

Comment: Hi, This did not work. Wonder if its because i am using 3.x version

Comment: The only change for this code to work in python 3.x is `print (pricing.getAttribute("catalogPrice"))` 
Rest everything should work. I just checked and its working in python3.5 When you say this did not work what error are you getting. May be that will help